# Concatenate two pandas dataframes with remaining the style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles, concatenation

[image]
I have two pandas dataframes(top and bottom)
You may see the style on the columns of the bottom dataframe.
I'd like to concat the two dataframes and keep the style. Is it possible? 
colab : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EpUe3f-5D_oqJJT-rKUnYadBImDnGpvG

Specifically, the top dataframe should go on the left(the 1st, 2nd columns) and the bottom dataframe should go on the right(the 3nd and rest columns).

Comment: Dataframe does not keep info of styling, just transform as you need, the statement with styling is: `df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues', subset=axis1000[4:8])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Phung Duy Phong

I did it by myself by

> types = {i*1000:float for i in range(1,11)}
>
> df = df.astype(types)

You might be able to see the solution on the colab file.